# joomla 2.5 standalone php JText::_() not working

Tags: php, joomla, module

I have a standalone file that generates an image, i included joomla framework. This file is displayed as image on the page. $_SESSION is empty and getUser returns NULL.
The JText does not know what module.language file to load and whats the default language for the user. How do I access this info/objects?

My code:

```
//define constant
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); 

//joomla installation
define( 'JPATH_BASE', '../..' );

//include joomla core files
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );

$echo = JText::_("MOD_MYMODULE_TEXT");

header("Content-type: image/png");
Graph::render($echo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('mod_sample',JPATH_ROOT,'fa-IR');
```

or sue this , detect lang automatically:

```
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('mod_sample',JPATH_ROOT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have been working with a component and have been using `JText::` successfully, and recently you have created a plugin and to your surprise the `JText::` class is not working, then please read below.

The Plugin uses its own language files. To load a language file automatically based on system language in `Joomla! 3.x` you need to use the following code.

```
$this->loadLanguage('', JPATH_BASE);
```

Furthermore you shall need to have a language file with the name based on the plugin name as follows.

```
<Language>.plg_<Plugin Type>_<Plugin name>.ini
```

So lets say your plugin name is `coolblue` and you are writing for the English (`en-GB`) language, and this plugin is of type `authentication`. So your file name would be ..

```
en-GB.plg_authentication_coolblue.ini
```

And you can store the language strings there. And `Joomla!` will load your language files for you, no need to discreetly specify any language or file.